# php variable undefined in javascript on FF and IE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a php variable and i use it in a javascript function. I get the result on chrome, but the variable was undefined on FF and IE. The alert() give: NaN.

```
<?php

require('connection.php');
$mod=$_POST['mod'];
$req=$bdd->prepare('SELECT * FROM theo WHERE affaire=?');
$req->execute(array($mod));
$tableau=$req->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

//var_dump($tableau);
foreach ($tableau as $key => $t)
{
  $date_theo_cre=$t['date_theo_cre'];
  $date_theo_fin=$t['date_theo_fin'];

}
$req->closeCursor();
?>

<script>
$(function(){
// Initialisation des champs
$('#dateJour').val(convertDateToString(new Date()));

});
var minDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo  $date_theo_cre;?>;"));
var today = new Date();
var maxDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo  $date_theo_fin;?>;"));
// Mise à jour de l'avancement

  var nbJoursTotal = Math.floor((maxDate.getTime() - minDate.getTime()) / 
 86400000);
  var nbJoursPasses = Math.floor((today.getTime() - minDate.getTime()) / 
 86400000);

  var pourcentage = nbJoursPasses / nbJoursTotal * 100;

  // On gère les cas limites
  if (pourcentage < 0) {
    pourcentage = 0;
  } else if (pourcentage > 100) {
    pourcentage = 100;
  }

  $("#avancement").reportprogress(pourcentage);

</script>
```

The call to the method: 
        $("#avancement").reportprogress(pourcentage);
give the result of the progress in an HTML div on chrome but nothing on FF and IE.

Can anyone please help me out?

Thanks

Comment: So what does the code look like after the PHP has executed? Hard to debug without knowiing what the PHP is spitting out and convertDateToString is doing.

Comment: My guess is you are passing invalid date string format to date object. Chrome is more forgiving about parsing invalid dates than other browsers

Comment: try to add a console.log minDate, maxDate, minDate.getTime() and maxDate.getTime() to see if your values are correct before calculations, chalietfl is probably right

Comment: If you're getting an error in JavaScript, the first thing you should be looking at is your actual resulting JavaScript code.  It seems reasonable that your PHP code isn't outputting what you assume it is, so what *is* it outputting?

Comment: `Date.parse("<?php echo  $date_theo_cre;?>;")`  extra colon is here. Remove it and check it once.

Comment: convertDateToString is just for display the date into french version in the html. And after php was executed, the javascript get the variables

Answer (score 3):

Can you try removing the unwanted semi-colon from the php statement like this:

```
var minDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo  $date_theo_cre;?>"));
var today = new Date();
var maxDate = new Date(Date.parse("<?php echo  $date_theo_fin;?>"));
```

Comment: Thanks to all of you.

Comment: Great. It will be good if you mark this as answer for other users.